# python pandas get ride of plural "s" in words to prepare for word count

Tags: python, pandas, word-count

I have the following python pandas dataframe:

```
Question_ID | Customer_ID | Answer
    1           234         The team worked very hard ...
    2           234         All the teams have been working together ...
```

I am going to use my code to count words in the answer column. But beforehand, I want to take out the "s" from the word "teams", so that in the example above I count team: 2 instead of team:1 and teams:1.

How can I do this for all words?

Comment: Easy exception to your idea : 'is' is not the plural of 'I'.

Comment: As iFlo said, this won't be easy. You need to consider the language rather than just every string you see. And what have you tried to do this? SO is not a code writing service in any way. I'm afraid your question is too broad.

Comment: To ensure this information remains available, this will remove the `'s'` from `df.Answer.str.replace(r'(\w{2,})s\b', r'\1')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a tokenizer (for breaking a sentence into words) and lemmmatizer (for standardizing word forms), both provided by the natural language toolkit `nltk`:

```
import nltk
wnl = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
[wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sentence)]
# ['All', 'the', 'team', 'have', 'been', 'working', 'together']
```

Answer (score 1):

use `str.replace` to remove the s from any 3 or more letter word that ends in `'s'`.

```
df.Answer.str.replace(r'(\w{2,})s\b', r'\1')

0                  The team worked very hard ...
1    All the team have been working together ...
Name: Answer, dtype: object
```

`'{2,}'` specifies 2 or more.  That combined with the `'s'` ensures that you'll miss `'is'`.  You can set it to `'{3,}'` to ensure you skip `'its'` as well.

Comment: This is still an unreliable approach. Converting to singular requires more than removing an 's' (woman/women).

Comment: @DYZ I agree this isn't great at finding equivalents.  But it is an attempt at doing so.  Language is fuzzy and it's difficult to provide a perfect solution.  I know I can't.  So I'll refrain from judging the approach OP is taking and instead provide the information they asked for and let them explore.

Answer (score 0):

Try the NTLK toolkit. Specifically Stemming and Lemmatization. I have never personally used it but [here](http://text-processing.com/demo/stem/) you can try it out.

Here is an example of some tricky plurals,

```
its it's his quizzes fishes maths mathematics
```

becomes

```
it it ' s hi quizz fish math mathemat
```

You can see it deals with "his" (and "mathematics") poorly, but then again you could have lots of abbreviated "hellos". This is the nature of the beast.